# Installing Ubuntu Server on a Supermicro M.2 NVMe PCIe gen4 drive - NVMe not found

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, supermicro

I'm currently trying to install Ubuntu server 22.04 LTS on a supermicro blade.

I've got two NVMe drives plugged and correctly fastened on the H12SSW-NT motherboard.
I'm unable to complete the installation : no drives are found. The drives are SOLIDIGM T41, I've been assured by my local hardware vendor that it's **totally** compatible .

On supermicro's website, the drive is not listed (but you never know when they update the lists) https://www.supermicro.com/en/support/resources/m2ssd?ProductID=86685&ProductName=H12SSW-NT

I've not messed up with the BIOS yet, the only thing I checked is the version, which is 2.5 and it's currently the latest. By googling furiously and after 4 hours of checking and rebooting and trying to install the OS, it seems that everything checks out by default, no need to change the BIOS PCIe configuration at all.

My USB Drive boots fine, in UEFI mode (GPT partitioning).
I'm unable to locate in the bios the drives at all, I've got no SATA drives in the bay currently and I'm tempted to buy one just to install the os to check if anything has to be done via software to get both NVMe drives to show up.
Any ideas what could be done to force the drives to show up ?
Thank you

Comment: Do they not show up in the _firmware_ menus (setup screens) or do they not show up in _Ubuntu_ live boot (lspci, lsblk)?

Comment: NVMe drives are NVMe drives.  The only compatibility you have to worry about is if you're attempting to say use PCIe 3 NVMe  drives in a system that supports PCIe 4 NVMe drives but even then, that problem is simple to solve.  The only reason, I personally can think the drives wouldn't show up, if they were already formatted.  I am too lazy to determine if the motherboard does or doesn't support PCIe 4 NVMe, scratch that, I am not entirely sure if a PCIe 4 NVMe device should be expected to work in a PCIe 3 NVMe slot.

Comment: There is also a possibility the drives are faulty.

Comment: Have you tried re-seating the M.2 drives?